# Ability to add additional data in dynamic sql query C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table like this in the Database.

Table A

- Column 1
- Column 2
- Column 3
- Column 4
- ActivityDate

Currently I have a method like this:

```
    private static string GenerateQuery(RequestModel requestModel)
    {
        var grouping = requestModel.ToGrouping();

        var whereClause = requestModel.ToWhereClause(grouping.WhereClause);

        var query = $@"SELECT      SUM(TableA.COlumnA) AS sumA,
                                    SUM(TableA.COlumnB) AS sumB,
                                    {grouping.GroupColumn}
                       FROM         TableA
                       {grouping.Join}
                       WHERE        TableA.ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateTime AND @endDateTime
                       {whereClause}
                       {grouping.GroupBy}
                       {toLimit.OrderBy}";

        return query;
    }
```

ToGrouping and ToWhereClause are extension methods which allows to return left joins and where string.
Now, Grouping.groupcolumn returns the columns on which to group by. How can I add ability to add additional data. For example if groupcolumn has a name and code and I want to return both. how can I add additional data in this method.

Comment: I would advise to be very careful generating sql like this. It's too easy to mess up and open yourself to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: thanks. this is client code and i dont have much control. how can I add extra data based on grouping.Column.